# javascript searching string with indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to search for a keycode in an array with array.indexOf(string); method but even though the keycode I am searching for is declared in the array it couldn't find it and returns -1 where am I mistaken?

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywrLP.png)

PS: However when I try to declare the string I'm trying the search manually (like var string = "219") it does work.

PS-2: As you can see in the console I'm logging the variable tusASII to ensure variable does have the right value to search for

```js
var tusASII = event.keyCode;
var trkarakterler = ["219","221","186","73","191","220"];
console.log(tusASII);
console.log(trkarakterler.indexOf(tusASII));
```

Comment: `keyCode` is not a string, it's a number.

Comment: console.log(trkarakterler.indexOf(tusASII + ''));
But is better if you user Number values instead... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a type mismatch. The array should contain numbers, like so:

```
 var trkarakterler = [219, 221, 186, 73, 191, 220];
```

The idea is that key codes are numbers, rather than strings.

Comment: Or, convert the search term to a string.

Comment: To be more accurate, there are no integers in JavaScript. The variable type is `number`.